# android studio action_set_alram logcat errors

Tags: android-studio

```js
enter c  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void AlarmS(View view){
 EditText hs= findViewById(R.id.h) ;
 EditText ms= findViewById(R.id.m);
 //숫자 타입으로 문자열 변환
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hs.getText().toString());
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(ms.getText().toString());
    AlarmSe(hour,minute);


}
public void AlarmSe(int hours, int minutes){
    Intent intent =new Intent(ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null)
    {
      startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        finish();
    }

}ode here
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDkGy.png)

this is logcat error 
have no problems with the build, but when I run the app and press the button, the app crashes.